# How to create custom otp input field for Angular App?

Tags: angular, input, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm working on Angular where I'm taking otp code. I want to add custom otp input not any third party package. If anyone know how to create one for angular specific will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by custom otp field? If it is just the field so make 4 or whatever inputs you need and you have to design it etc. Is that what you need? What have you code so far ?

Comment: I was facing this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71949508/ng-otp-input-isnt-working-properly-inside-material-stepper-otp-input-gets-disa

Comment: Custom otp means I want 6 boxes in one input field.

Comment: use this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-otp-input

Answer (score 1):

You can create and use OTP Input through the following [link](https://dev.to/rajeshkumaryadavdotcom/angular-how-to-add-a-fully-customizable-one-time-password-input-component-in-your-angular-app-just-in-10-minutes-n29)

1- Install npm Package

```
npm install --save ng-otp-input
```

2- Import NgOtpInputModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgOtpInputModule } from 'ng-otp-input';

@NgModule({ 
declarations: [AppComponent], 
imports: [BrowserModule, NgOtpInputModule], 
bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
})
```

3- Use It!

```
<ng-otp-input (onInputChange)="onOtpChange($event)" [config]="{length:5}"></ng-otp-input>
```

You can also see the live demo [here](https://rajeshkumaryadav.com/#/auth)